# scala generic double brackets literal

Tags: scala, generics, literals

I'm learning Scala's generic content, and I don't know the meaning of literal in the code

```scala
sealed trait Natural

sealed trait Vect[N <: Natural, +A]:
  def length: Int

  def map[B](f: A => B): Vect[N, B]

  def zip[B](that: Vect[N, B]): Vect[N, (A, B)]

  def concat[M <: Natural, B >: A](that: Vect[M, B]): Vect[Plus[N, M], B]
```

What does `Vect[N, (A, B)]` mean, especially `(A, B)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Vect` is a type with 2 type parameters. The 1st must be some form of (sub-type of) `Natural`, we'll call it `N`. The 2nd is some unrestricted type defined at the call-site, we'll call it `A`.

The `zip()` method receives a different `Vect`. It must have the same 1st-parameter type (not just any `Natural`, it has to be the same) but the 2nd-parameter type might be different, we'll call it `B`. (It might be the same as `A` but it might not so it needs a different identifier.)

The `zip()` method returns a new `Vect` with the same 1st-parameter type but the 2nd type parameter is a 2-element tuple (a 2-ple) with the 1st element of type `A` and the 2nd element of type `B`.

The `A` and `B` have been "zipped" together.

Comment: Thanks @jwvh. I know that Vect[N,(A,B)] ,(A,B) is 2-element tuple.

Answer (score 3):

`(A,B)` is type for tuple.

scala api has definition for zip, which is similar.

ref: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tuples.html

Comment: Thanks, I just know that scala can use  a generic tuple